My position was eliminated…
My position was eliminated, I was involuntarily terminated by the company.  My termination date was the end of the month but my employer added an additional month and added that my employment could be extended up to two years based on the “need”. They stated if I did not stay the additional month and agree and meet  all the requirements my severance pay would be denied. They also added a paragraph that stated if my boss was not satisfied with my performance during my requested extended employment period my severance would be denied.  My boss is a real b*****, anything sets her insecurities off. Lastly they stated I must sign the ETA which take’s away my right to sue.  Is all of this legal?

They can not force you to sign anything.

Which state and are you under a contract?

What you describe sounds more like a performance plan, outside of your severance being denied, which without understanding what state you are in might or might not be legal. Most people don’t get a severance when they are fired for performance reasons.

@Donald What you're referring to are objectively demonstrable and measurable performance shortcomings. This wouldn't fly for a vague "unhappy with performance" mention. However, if OP signs this document, it opens to the door to vague performance reviews being a cause for firing without severance. OP needs to tread very carefully here because the company would not be putting this in writing unless OP would be trading away some of their benefits over the promise of potentially extended employment.

@Flater - I don't necessarily disagree that the author should tread carefully, but their description of their supervisor isn't the most professional.  So, I am less inclined to believe there isn't a performance issue. It also is weird that there is a performance issue, but that month might be extended to 2 years, which suggests a contract, not a full-time employee of the company. Most individuals in the US don't have an employment contract.

@Donald Ehh, that's wrong. Most Americans DO have an employment contract. They just don't know they signed one. However, due to "At Will" employment, most people don't pay attention to it. However, what's catching me is the ETA here. Signing an ETA may be related to the US DOL, possibly foreign worker or visa related. This question needs some clarification on which ETA form it is. As if it is a US DOL ETA form, the employer cannot modify it. There are multiple forms being discussed, with no clarity as to what request is associated with which form.

This sucks and I would recommend you talk to a lawyer.  You are understandably emotional but I can also see the company's perspective.
Lets say you do agree to the extra month to get the severance, then start behaving like a real jerk possibly sabotaging the company and destroying equipment.  It would be silly to pay such a person severance.
On the other hand they try to work you to death for 23 months with no bumps in salary.  Then the last month you get called into the office saying your performance has been crap. Sorry no severance.
Depending on the amount of the severance this may not be worth it as keshlam said.
Sorry you lost your job and hopefully this is a beginning of something better for you.

Severance benefits are usually conditional, so yes, this is probably all perfectly legal. You have the option of not signing, and not getting those benefits. Some people prefer that. Personally, I recommend you carefully read what they are asking you to agree to, and then make an informed choice rather than letting a gut reaction push you either way. The only question here is what's best for you, given the limited set of options you have available.
And yes, if anything seems unclear or odd, a quick consultation with a lawyer may be a good investment.

Do not sign anything (in my opinion)
Nothing they're doing is illegal, but I think the company is tricking you into signing your rights away.
This very much sounds like you're being offered a promise of employment, not as an attempt to actually keep you employed, but to get you to sign away your severance pay so that it would cost the company even less to get rid of you.

"Hey, we might keep you employed longer, but only if you definitely waive your rights, ability to sue us for anything we do, and give us permission to arbitrarily fire you without severance."

Does that sound like a trustworthy offer of employment to you? Because that's what's on offer here.
When you sign this document, the company is able to easily fire you by claiming they're "not happy with your performance" (which they can subjectively argue whenever they feel like it) and get you out of there without the company needing to pay you any severance.
This all stinks to high heaven. Do not sign anything. Let them fire you based on the existing contract you have with them, which I'm inferring includes a severance payment, and find a different job.

@JoeStrazzere: That seems to be an inaccuracy in the OP's description, as they would have already been paid (or at least guaranteed to be paid) their due severance if that were the case, meaning that the company's insistence on not paying severance would be moot. Based on the provided context, it appears that the company is offering to hold off on the firing if OP signs this new deal with the promise of possibly extended employment. My read on this is that it is an attempt by the company to get out of needing to pay severance, while still intending to get rid of OP in either case.

@JoeStrazzere "my severance pay would be denied" (quote by OP) suggests that there is severance pay, albeit that the company is currently finding ways in which to be able to choose to deny it. Your mention of "If the OP doesn't sign there is no severance payment." implies that the company is now suddenly offering severance payment that wasn't there before, after they're already fired him (as per your own interpretation mentioned in your comment), which is nonsensical. "We've fired you, but we'll give you money you weren't entitled to, and maybe keep you employed longer"???

@Flater Some times, severance payments are discretionary. By not agreeing, you may be literally kissing away thousands of dollars. Best to seek professional help if it's unclear what is in your best interests.

@GregoryCurrie: The only options for firing in this new deal (as listed by the OP) are firings without severance. Where are you getting the information that by signing this new deal, the OP is somehow going to get a severance that they otherwise would not have gotten? (I'm not asking whether his severance was already discretionary, I'm asking why you think that these added constraints in the new deal would make the employer more likely to choose to discretionarily pay out severance, and in what case you think this would apply)

"They stated if I did not stay the additional month and agree and meet all the requirements my severance pay would be denied."

@GregoryCurrie: I see you're inferring that this implies that OP would be given severance if they were to stay more than a month and not display any performance issues until they get fired for other reasons (which also somehow don't invalidate their severance); but this does not indicate an increase in the likelihood of receiving severance. If the company is able to discretionarily pay severance now, they can do so in the future as well. Nothing here mentions any kind of increase in the willingness to pay severance. This is all a vague and inferred promise to get OP to sign other things away.

@GregoryCurrie: Furthermore, if OP weren't getting any severance now anyway, the question is rendered moot from the get go, because clearly the company has no reason to somehow start paying severance out of the goodness of their heart in the future but just not today. While this may be a legal reality, it's irrelevant for the purpose of the question as nothing the OP does today would guarantee a severance payment (even if all criteria are met) down the line.

Severance is often not required by contract or law, but as a gesture of goodwill. If, in this case it is a gesture of goodwill, it's better off the OP consulting with a legal expert, rather than flatly refusing to sign as you suggest.

And, of course, if the OP is unsure on their entitlements, best to consult a legal expert rather than just assume they are better off not signing.


Is all of this legal?

I don't see anything that seems illegal.
If you think you want to sue, don't sign the document and forgo the severance pay.

I agree with Joe, but there are also unknowns here. If severance is required (by state law or contract), it could be illegal.
